# Adding an Open Activity to a specific opportunity

Tags: apex, opportunity, related-list

I want to add all the open activities from an opportunity to another opportunity. From my understanding, open activity is split into `event` and `task`. This is what I have so far :

```
List<Opportunity> rec = [Select Id, (Select ActivityDate,Description,
                        Subject FROM OpenActivities) FROM Opportunity
                        WHERE id='123456789'];

for(Opportunity a : rec) {
    System.debug(a.OpenActivities);
}
```

This is printing out the fields that I've specified (ActivityDate,Description,Subject) but since Open Activities can be either an event or task, so I'm unsure how I would check for that. I think I've found a field of the name `ActivitySubtype` but I guess what my issue is, even in this example, I'm not able to access only the `Description` of `OpenActivities`. Not really sure how to do that...

And I really have no idea how to insert an `Open Activity` event/task into an opportunity. I'm reading around for it right now but it would help to get some possible advice/guidance on that too

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [OpenActivity](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_openactivity.htm) documentation to help you out; notably there's a field called "IsTask" that tells you if you're working with a task or event. You could pull the descriptions like this:

```
for(Opportunity a : rec) {
    for(OpenActivity b: a.OpenActivities) {
        System.debug(b.Description);
    }
}
```

That said, I'd personally rather get the individual objects separately since you intend to be working with them directly:

```
Opportunity[] rec = [SELECT (SELECT ActivityDate, Description FROM Tasks 
                             WHERE IsClosed = FALSE),
                            (SELECT ActivityDate, Description FROM Events 
                             WHERE ActivityDate >= TODAY)
                     FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = '006000012356155'];
```

This would probably be easier to work with, because you can't actually *insert* OpenActivities (it's a "view" of two objects); you have to manipulate the underlying data, so simply querying those records directly is going to be easier.

Comment: Thanks! So I can't use `Apex` to insert all the open activities to another opportunity. I feel like there has to be way, still looking around tho

Comment: @user2582622 *nothing* can insert OpenActivities. It's not a "real" object: you need to insert Task and Event records instead.